# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called after programatically selecting row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

At various points during my app's execution it is required to programatically select a row of a UITableView using

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

This works fine and the row is highlighted and marked as selected in the backend.  The table is configured to allow multiple selections.

However, if the user subsequently deselects this row the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" function is not being called.  The strange thing is, if they reselect it, the function is called again as would be expected.

Any idea what could be going wrong?  Is there an additional property or something that should be reset when selecting the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user subsequently deselects the row, the associated `UITableViewDelegate` method will be called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks!  A long day of coding left me not thinking straight in the end.  This is obviously the answer to my question, selected for being first.

Comment: We've all been there! Thanks Ian

Answer (score 3):

Implement `UITableViewDelegate` protocol
.h:

```
@interface YourView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

then in .m:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

then write:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath[
}
```

and your method will be call

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for selecting/deselecting rows in `UITableViewDelegate` :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should not expect delegate methods to be called if you triggered the action from code. They will only be triggered by user interaction. If you programmatically set the cell to selected then it is only natural that the user interaction to deselect will trigger the associated delegate method.